# Why is cy.intercept() causing my API request to return a 400 bad request response?

Tags: cypress, http-status-code-400, intercept

I am running into an issue in cypress where my API request is returning a 400 bad response ONLY when it is being intercepted. I am only using cy.intercept() to spy on the request, not to manipulate it. When I remove the intercept command from the test, the request returns a 200 response. In both cases (with / without the intercept), the request headers are identical. I can also take the request headers from the intercepted 400 response, and run them in postman which returns a 200 response. cy.intercept() only seems to cause this issue on GET requests, not POST ones.

Ex. If I do something like:

```
it('Should Do something', () => {   
cy.intercept('GET', '/api/rest/v2/my-featured-courses/').as('getCourses'); // declaring the GET        
cy.login();   
cy.visit('/'); 
})
```

The intercepted request will return a 400 response.

If I do:

```
it('Should Do something', () => {   
cy.login();   
cy.visit('/'); 
})
```

Without the intercept, the request returns a 200 response.

Comment: Please add the code you're trying to execute, as well as an example request/response from your API.

Comment: Have you solved this by now ?

Answer (score 1):

try to brake it down a bit. Declare your GET request at the very begining of your test then perform some actions and then insert wait for your response. see my example below:

```
it('Should Do something', () => {
  cy.intercept('GET', '/api/rest/v2/my-featured-courses/').as('getCourses'); // declaring your GET
    
  cy.login();
  cy.visit('/');
  cy.wait('@getCourses') // using your intercepted GET

  cy.get('#Button').click();
  cy.get('.md-dialog').should('be.visible');
```

});

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Waiting-on-a-request

Comment: Declaring the GET request at the beginning of the test also causes the 400 response, even if I don't use it (ex. cy.wait('@getCourses')) later on.

Comment: did you try to to put full URL instead of just "/api/rest/v2/my-featured-courses/" ?